# Why the result of this integral?

Tags: integration

I have to resolve this integral:

$$\int e^{-2t}u(t)dt$$

Where $u(t)$ is heaviside's function. The result should be:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-2t}}{2}\right)u(t)$$

but I don't undestand why this result. Someone could explain me the step to get it?

Comment: Is that Heaviside's function the one that equals 1 for positive argument, zero for negative one and whatever (many times, $\,0.5\,$) for zero? I doubt it as then I can't see how could you get what you say you do from the integral...

Comment: Yes the heaviside function is that you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you give an indefinite integral, a constant of integration should be added. However, if we wish to compute
$$
\int_0^xe^{-2t}u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
We can proceed as follows. For $x<0$, since $u(t)=0$ when $t<x<0$, we get
$$
\int_0^xe^{-2t}u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0\tag{1}
$$
For $x\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^xe^{-2t}u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^xe^{-2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\tfrac{1}{2}\left[e^{-2x}-e^{0}\right]\\
&=\tfrac12-\tfrac12e^{-2x}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together yields
$$
\int_0^xe^{-2t}u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\left[\tfrac12-\tfrac12e^{-2x}\right]u(x)\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

...but if the Heaviside function you mention is what I said, then the function $\,e^{-2t}u(t)\,$ is zero on the negative reals and thus $$\int e^{-2t}u(t)\,dt=\int e^{-2t}\,dt=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}+C\,,\,\,C=\,\text{constant}$$ only when $\,t> 0\,$

I think that what you ***really*** had is something like $\,\,\displaystyle{\int_0^t e^{-2x}u(x)\,dx}\,\,$ , which gives exactly what you said, so that the integral isn't zero only if $\,t>0\,$ , but without the limits the integral is indefinite and you can't get what you say you did.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The form of the answer should remind you of [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts): $\int_a^b f(t)g'(t)dt=f(t)g(t)|_a^b-\int_a^b f'(t)g(t)dt$  This  will depend upon some properties of $u(t)$